# Symfony 4 custom container aware command error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am trying to create custom command in Symfony 4 project

```
class AppOauthClientCreateCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

   protected function configure()
   {
     $this
        ->setName('app:oauth-client:create')
        ->setDescription('Create a new OAuth client');
   }

   protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
   {
    $clientManager = $this->getContainer()->get('fos_oauth_server.client_manager.default');
    $client = $clientManager->createClient();
    $client->setAllowedGrantTypes(array(OAuth2::GRANT_TYPE_USER_CREDENTIALS));
    $clientManager->updateClient($client);

    $output->writeln(sprintf('client_id=%s_%s', $client->getId(), $client->getRandomId()));
    $output->writeln(sprintf('client_secret=%s', $client->getSecret()));
   }
}
```

I am getting following error when I try to run this command

> The "fos_oauth_server.client_manager.default" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either
>      make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

How do I make vendor service public or am I missing something in command configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that all services are private by deafault since Symfony 4. In fact it is not possible to get a private service using `get` method of the service container.

You should avoid injecting the entire contanier in your services (or commands by extending `ContainerAwareCommand`). Instead you should inject only the needed services:

```
class AppOauthClientCreateCommand
{
   /**
    * @var ClientManagerInterface
    */
   private $clientManager;

   public function __construct(ClientManagerInterface $clientManager)
   {
       $this->clientManager = $clientManager;
   }

   protected function configure()
   {
       ...
   }

   protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
   {
        $client = $this->clientManager->createClient();
        ...
   }
}
```

If `ClientManagerInterface` is not autowired then you must configure your `AppOauthClientCreateCommand` with proper dependency in your services.yaml. Something like:

```
services:
    App\Command\AppOauthClientCreateCommand:
        arguments:
            $clientManager: "@fos_oauth_server.client_manager.default"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check the `./bin/console debug:autowiring` command's output for the appropriate interface to use 'fos_oauth_server.client_manager.*' in the constructor. Autowiring should already be setup to allow for the container to recognise and insert it from there.

This will require FosOauthServer support for SF4 - and in the constructor remember to also call `parent::__construct();` to properly setup the command. You can do that and still use the ContainerAwareCommand to `->get()` other things from the container - but you will likely move away from that over time.